# Set Adaptive Card to Currency With Parameter From Apply to Each?

Tags: json, power-automate, adaptive-cards

[image: Currency Example1]

[image]

In the image above it changes the adaptive card to Currency. How can I add this with a parameter from somewhere else? I am trying to do this but it is not working.

```
"value": "${formatNumber(@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Cost Each']}, 2)}"
```

How can I get this code to show as currency? It seems to be that when I use "@{items" it will not work. Any suggestions?
Here is the adaptive card. I am looping through Excel data and want to put the Parameters I received from Excel into an Adaptive Card and use the $$ Format.

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
      {
          "type": "Container",
          "style": "emphasis",
          "items": [
              {
                  "type": "ColumnSet",
                  "columns": [
                      {
                          "type": "Column",
                          "items": [
                              {
                                  "type": "TextBlock",
                                  "size": "Large",
                                  "weight": "Bolder",
                                  "text": "**PART APPROVAL**"
                              }
                          ],
                          "width": "stretch"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ],
          "bleed": true
      },
      {
          "type": "Container",
          "items": [
              {
                  "type": "ColumnSet",
                  "columns": [
                      {
                          "type": "Column",
                          "items": [
                              {
                                  "type": "TextBlock",
                                  "size": "ExtraLarge",
                                  "text": "New Part Approval",
                                  "wrap": true
                              }
                          ],
                          "width": "stretch"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "type": "FactSet",
                  "spacing": "Large",
                  "facts": [
                      {
                          "title": "Part #:",
                          "value": "**@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Part Number']}**"
                      },
                      {
                          "title": "Description:",
                          "value": "@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Description']}"
                      },
                      {
                          "title": "Quantity:",
                          "value": "@{items('Apply_to_each')?['AOQ']}"
                      },
                      {
                          "title": "Cost Each:",
                          "value": "@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Cost Each']}"
                      },
                      {
                          "title": "Sell Each:",
                          "value": "@{items('Apply_to_each')?['Sell Each']}"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "type": "Container",
          "items": [
              {
                  "type": "ActionSet",
                  "actions": [
                      {
                          "type": "Action.Submit",
                          "title": "Approve",
                          "style": "positive",
                          "data": {
                              "id": "_qkQW8dJlUeLVi7ZMEzYVw",
                              "action": "approve"
                          },
                          "id": "ApproveID"
                      },
                      {
                          "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                          "title": "Reject",
                          "style": "destructive",
                          "card": {
                              "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                              "body": [
                                  {
                                      "type": "Input.Text",
                                      "id": "RejectCommentID",
                                      "placeholder": "Please specify an appropriate reason for rejection.",
                                      "isMultiline": true
                                  }
                              ],
                              "actions": [
                                  {
                                      "type": "Action.Submit",
                                      "title": "Send",
                                      "data": {
                                          "id": "_qkQ8dJlUeMVi7ZMEzYVf",
                                          "action": "reject"
                                      }
                                  }
                              ],
                              "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
                          },
                          "id": "RejectID"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.2",
  "fallbackText": "This card requires Adaptive Cards v1.2 support to be rendered properly."
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Ethan, could you maybe post your full card (and maybe sample data aswell) so we can see where exactly you're using this?

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the response. Please see the updated post and let me know if this isn't enough information or not.

Comment: Hey Ethan, didn't see you're in Power Automate first , can you try this maybe?

"value": "@{formatNumber(items('Apply_to_each')?['Cost Each'], 2)}"

No idea if that works can't try it right now but as far as i know PA does not use the ${} but @{}

Comment: Hi Tim, no that didn't work. Thanks for the thought though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for that.

Just asked a colleague and the new Adaptive Expressions, the one you're using there to format currencies are actually not working on Power Automate yet.

Power Automate is not updated to the latest Adaptive Cards version so some of the things you can do with cards are not available in flows yet.

Tim